# Can't retrieve xml element in mule through xpath3

Tags: mule, xpath-3.0

**Code to save the card number in the card number variable from request.**

```
<set-variable variableName="cardNumber" value="#[xpath3('//@CardNumber', message.payload,'STRING')]" doc:name="Set cardNumber"/>
<logger level="INFO" message=" #[xpath3('//@CardNumber', message.payload, 'STRING')]" />
<logger message="#[flowVars['operationName']] cardNumber is = #[flowVars['cardNumberr']]" level="INFO" category="member" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

**Below is the payload**

```
mlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://ws.loyalty.com/cpm/esb/amrp/2/1/member/types">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <typ:GetMemberProfileRequest>
         <typ:RequestContext Channel="WEB" Source="" Locale="" User="ONLINEUSER"/>
         <typ:CardNumber>80000000021</typ:CardNumber>
      </typ:GetMemberProfileRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The card number is coming empty string in logs

Answer (score 0):

@esha sherry, the xpath3 expression to get the card number should be

```
#[xpath3('/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/typ:GetMemberProfileRequest/typ:CardNumber', message.payload, 'STRING')]
```

Comment: Exception stack is:
Execution of the expression "xpath3('/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/typ:GetMemberProfileRequest/typ:CardNumber', message.payload, 'STRING')" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.grumble(XPathParser.java:267)
  net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.makeNameCode(XPathParser.java:2808)

Comment: Message               : Execution of the expression "xpath3('/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/typ:GetMemberProfileRequest/typ:CardNumber', message.payload, 'STRING')" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException).
Element               : /SOAPServiceRouterSkipFacade/processors/0/0/3/1/4/0/4 @ celo-esb-main-flow-1.2.0.21:MemberService.xml:215

Comment: Will it be possible to post your entire configuration XML? Because I am successfully able to generate an output, based on the input you've provided with the same expression.

Comment: is xml to dom transformer required?

Comment: that payload is the entire request

Comment: or splitter expression is required to grab a value from the request?

Comment: This is the code which is working for me.                <mulexml:namespace-manager includeConfigNamespaces="true">
        <mulexml:namespace prefix="typ" uri="http://ws.loyalty.com/cpm/esb/amrp/2/1/member/types" />
 <mulexml:namespace prefix="soapenv" uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
</mulexml:namespace-manager>
<flow name="xyz">
        <httpconfig/>
        <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="BATS"/>
<logger level="INFO" message="#[xpath3('/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/typ:GetMemberProfileRequest/typ:CardNumber', message.payload, 'STRING')]" doc:name="L"/>

Comment: Pardon the formatting. It's due to character limit. Let me know if you are doing something like this. If not, please share your code.